# Can't get Facebook Email

Tags: python, facebook, oauth, oauth-2.0

I'm following [this tutorial here](http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/oauth-authentication-with-flask) and I have the following code with the python library Rauth and Flask:

```
def callback(self):
    if 'code' not in request.args:
        return None, None, None
    oauth_session = self.service.get_auth_session(
        data={'code': request.args['code'],
              'grant_type': 'authorization_code',
              'redirect_uri': self.get_callback_url()}
    )
    me = oauth_session.get('me').json()
    print me['id'], me['name'], me.get('email')
    return ('facebook$' + me['id'], me.get('email').split('@')[0],  # Facebook does not provide username, so the email's user is used instead
        me.get('email'))
```

As you can see, I try to print `me['id'], me['name'], me.get('email')`. The id and name print as planned though the email prints as None causing an issue with the function (as the email is used at the bottom of the function). When testing this with my personal Facebook account, I made sure I provided the email, I checked the app settings and where it says email, there is a marked checkbox stating that I'm sharing an email with this application.

Has Facebook changed the way the email is handled or received or is there an issue with my app or code? Thanks.

Comment: So this is also happening with your own account? Is that registered with your app? Can you provide your app ID and your own ID, please?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently whit the update to version 2.4 of the APIs Facebook removed the email from the list of fields returned.

If your APP uses version 2.4 of the API you should probably exclude the email field from your code.

For reference:
https://developers.facebook.com/ads/blog/post/2015/07/08/marketing-api-v2_4/

Stefano